# Error in prime factorization in java if a number greater than 11 digits or greater is given

Tags: java

Whenever I give a number greater than 10 digits, it gives me an error saying `Error:Integer too large` even though I have used `long` data type everywhere.

Here is my program:

```
class q3 {
    boolean prime(long a) {
        long c=0;
        for(long i=1;i<=a;i++) {
            if(a%i==0) {
                c++;
            }
        }
        if(c==2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void main(long a) { 
        boolean result=false;
            for(long i=1;i<=a/2;i++) {
                if(a%i==0) {
                    result=prime(i);
                } else {
                    result=false;
                }
                if(result==true) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: You can use the `BigInteger` class to avoid such overflows.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have given that would say *"Error:Integer too large"*.  There is no code for "giving" a number here either.  Please explain how / where you are getting this message.

Comment: @PaulVargas Actually, StackOverflow deprecated the homework tag. Please do not assign it to any new posts. Just FYI.

Comment: @PaulVargas read the [tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info). It is no longer desired.

Comment: @ZoveGames - use a capital L ... it is much easier distinguish it from the digit 1 than a lower case l is.

Comment: @Tom So what do you do when a student asks a question? Is there such a difference or not anymore?

Comment: @PaulVargas - IMO, if the question appears to be genuine you answer it with hints ... as always.  Otherwise vote to close as "too localized" or some such.  That is likely to happen anyway ... because homework questions are generally only of interest to the person asking them.

Comment: (@StephenC thanks for the advice.) Remember to add L after literals to make the data type a long. Ex. Instead of 4444 type 4444L which will make it a long.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of possible explanations of how you might get an error saying the the number is too large.  But the problem is not in the code you presented.

I suspect that the problem is that you are trying to call the `main` method like this:

```
new q().main(1234567890);
```

That fails because `1234567890` is an `int` literal, not a `long` literal.  Write it like this:

```
new q().main(1234567890L);
```

---

Notes:

1. This will work for 18-19 digit numbers.  Beyond that you will need to use BigInteger.
2. Testing primality that way is *extremely* slow for large numbers.  There are much more efficient ways of doing it.  Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).
3. Even if you test primality this way, the `prime(a)` method can stop when it reaches `sqrt(a)`.  And it *should* stop when you find any factor (greater than 1) ... rather than counting them all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find when you start to get up to very large numbers of iterations (like `long`s), you'll want to get away from `for` loops and start using `while` loops.

Here is what you had:

```
for(long i = 1; i <= a/2; i++)
```

But the `for` loop is really meant for countable sets. When you have something other than an `int` as the iterand of your `for` loop you have to consider the second and third arguments more carefully:

```
i <= a/2;
```

Is `a/2` an `int`? Is it a `long`? Do you need to write:

```
i <= ((long) a)/2L;
```

Suddenly, this becomes much more complicated. When you write:

```
i++;
```

Do you know for certain that the `++` operator works on `long` values? Probably. But you should check.

Typically, serious mathematical models/calculations use `while` loops because:

```
while(i < someValue)
```

is an easy-to-understand statement with very little ambiguity. You will iterate `i` (which could be a `long` or a `BigInteger`, or whatever) inside the `while` loop, and reduce how much you really need to understand about the arguments of that `for` statement.

You may have another problem in your program, it is hard to tell how you are calling this class. But I think you should start by re-writing these loops either way.